# How to merge tables that don't have the same columns in Talend

Tags: sql, etl, talend

For a project I'm using Talend, and I have 5 tables that have almost the same columns. But some of the tables have extra columns specific to the table
For the moment I've been using tUnite to merge table that have the same columns

I would like to keep them while merging those table and I have no idea how to do it

Example :

> Table 1 :  col a, col b, col c
>
> Table 2 :  col a, col b, col c
>
> Table 3 :  col a, col b, col c, col d

I would like that when I'm merging those table col d is merge but appear with no values (blank or null, whatever) for table 1 and table 2

Is there any component that could help me do that ?
Am I missing something obvious ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your job should be designed as below :

```
tdbinput1(table 1) -> main                       -> 
                                                 |
tdbinput2(table 2) ->    main                    ->   tunite -> tlogrow
                                                 |
tdbinput3(table 3) -> main ->tFilterColumns->main
```

In the `tFilterColumns` component you can ignore your `col d`

See below documentation of `tFilterColumns`

https://help.talend.com/r/fr-FR/7.2/processing/tfiltercolumns-standard-properties

Or if `col d`  is needed just add the columns using tMap component

```
tdbinput1(table 1) -> main ->tmap1 (add col d)    -> 
                                                 |
tdbinput2(table 2) ->    main ->tmap2 (add col d)                ->   tunite -> tlogrow
                                                 |
tdbinput3(table 3) ->  main
```

Comment: The thing is (as said in the post) I don't want to loose additional columns

Answer (score 1):

tUnite will require that all schemas are the same.
Most convenient solution would be to add columns to table 1 and 2 (through a tMap for example) with null value, so schema of tables 1/2 would be the same as table3.